# I cannot plot the table below the chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt

I'm having a difficult to plot the table below the chunck when I run it. It appears nothing.

Below is the code:

```
## Tabela dos 10 Estados com mais acidentes
DezMaisEstados2 <- DezMaisEstados %>%
  slice(1:10) %>% 
    gt() %>%
      fmt_percent(
        columns = Freq_relativa,
        decimals = 2
      ) %>% 
      cols_align(align = "center") %>% 
      tab_header(
        title = md("**Ranking de Acidentes por Estado**"),
        subtitle="Top 10"
      ) %>% 
      tab_footnote(
        footnote="Fonte: PRF (2017)",
        locations = cells_title(groups = "title")
      )
DezMaisEstados2
```

If I run on the console I can have the plot, like attached picture:

Table plot on the console

[image]

Does anyone know how to plot the table below the chunk?

Comment: Can you show the chunk code

Comment: Have you added `library(gt)` to the chunk?

Comment: The reason I mentioned about the `chunk` is that you can disable a chunk without evaluating by `eval = FALSE` etc.  If you have copy/pasted a chunk config from some other place and forgot to remove those...

Comment: @TarJae ! Yes I inserter the library(gt). Does it have a problem?

Comment: @wil. your code works with `mtcars` dataset on my machine. so we need the chunk and the possible error code to help.

Comment: Hi @akrun ! This is the chunk setup: ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi TarJae. The is no error code. It runs, but does not appear below the chunk the table. Only on console.

Comment: Hi @akrun ! Unfortunately it did not work inserting include = FALSE

Comment: Do you have the latest package versions

Comment: Yes @akrun ! I installed today some packages.